# Assign unit of css variable

Tags: css, css-variables

Is it possible to assign type of unit to a CSS variable inside of the CSS property?

```
:root {
    --width: 400;
}

.class {
    width: var(--width); //assign 'px' as unit?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using the `calc()` function by multiplying your `var` which don't have `px` value by `1px` as in example:

As this will transform the value to `px` at the end.
I searched a lot but I think there is no way to just add `px` to the `var` without `calc()`.

```css
:root {
    --width: 200;
}

div.a {
    width: calc(var(--width) * 1px);
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>

<div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This approach does not seem to work with `fr` units.